# Positioning won't work in relative layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a small problem. Please see image below:

[image]

I had problems positioning TextView1 above edittext, so i checked this forum for great solution. I was using `android:layout_above="@id/edittext"`, but it seems it was not working. Then i tried `android:layout_below="@id/textview"`, and it worked nicely. But now i have other problem. I can't align TextView1 on the top center of edittext below. I tried layout_align options but most of them throws exception "some circular thing".

Where is the catch? Below is my XML ( of relative layout )

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/workingTimeTV"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
       android:text="TextView1" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/hoursET"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:text="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="6"
        android:layout_below="@id/workingTimeTV"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="number" >
        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/hoursTV"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="25sp"
       android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hoursET"
       android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/hoursET"
       android:text="h" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: align left and right and use gravity in the textview

Comment: Nice trick. thanks.. yours works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you assuming that if set  **`android:gravity="center"`** that align child in center, but it not works with relative layout, so you use    **`android:layout_centerVertical="true"`** every child     whatever you want to position in center. Following modified code will fulfill your expectation.

```
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/workingTimeTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="TextView1" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/hoursET"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/workingTimeTV"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="6"
            android:text="1" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hoursTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@id/hoursET"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/hoursET"
            android:text="h"
            android:textSize="25sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

below code can help you

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/workingTimeTV"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="TextView1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

use android:layout_centerInParent="true" to place your textbox in center and also use relative layout for doing this.